# Magento 2 Paypal Express Checkout order on hold

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, paypal

I've set up a **Magento 2.3.0** shop, and as a payment method, I'm also using **Paypal express checkout**.
The **"Payment Action"** is set to **"Authorization"**, and I have received an order a few days ago, the amount is shown in the **paypal account on hold**, saying **"Authorization"**.
Is there anything else I should do in order to actually receive the amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to PayPal Developer Documentation, **[authorization](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECSettlements/#authorization-payment-action)** enables you to capture multiple payments up to 115% of the originally authorized amount(not to exceed an increase of $75 USD).

Choose this payment action if you need to ship the goods before capturing the payment or if there is some reason not to accept the payment immediately.

The honor period, for which funds can be held, **is three days.** The valid period, for which the authorization is valid, **is 29 days.** You can reauthorize the 3-day honor period at most once within the 29-day valid period.

So to answer your question on what to do to actually receive the amount immediately, you just need to accept the payments from your PayPal account manually.